# AWS requires TLS1.2 but ASP.NET making requests with TLS 1.0 or 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services

my c# .NET code has been compiled and targeting .NET 4.8.  My Windows .NET webserver is running .NET 4.8 but I continue to get messages back from AWS when invoking their API that says the operation is illegal and that I need to update my TLS calls to 1.2.  Here is the exact error message that I receive.

"AccessDenied", error message "Caller is not authorized to call this service over TLS 1.0/1.1.".

The user agent reported is:

"aws-sdk-dotnet-45/3.7.301.2 aws-sdk-dotnet-core/3.7.300.9 .NET_Runtime/4.0 .NET_Framework/4.0 OS/Microsoft_Windows_NT_10.0.17763.0 ClientSync"

I'm not sure if this is the correct user agent for .NET 4.8 or not, it certainly doesn't seem so which leads me to ask, why is my code running under .NET 4.0 and not .NET 4.8?

I've been through recommended edits to the Registry to configure my .NET environment to default to TLS 1.2 and it is not working.

Comment: Which versions of Windows and .NET Framework are installed on the web server?

Comment: You need to add `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />` to your config file. otherwise it defaults to handling it the same way as 4.5 even if 4.8 is running

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an old code running, not .NET 4.8 as you might think.

Depending on the version combination, the TLS version selection changes.

For newer .NET versions it relies on the OS to do the decision and most times that works. But older ones (like the one I'd assume you have) do choose the TLS and it's always to an old TLS version.

This page explains how to set the OS registry to ensure TLS 1.2 is used:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#systemdefaulttlsversions

You can save this as a `.reg` file and run on the machine (as administrator) to automatically set it for you:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```

> Source: the same link, just copied to here for convenience.

Comment: Incidentally, you can also harden the server by disallowing things like SSL, TLS 1.0, etc. There's a [tool from nartac.com](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) that makes it easier than editing the registry manually. (I have no connection to Nartac Software.)

Comment: Based on direction by AWS I have set the following registry according to the same suggestions that @AndrewMorton responded with before this stack post and I have tested it as well and it is not working, so something else is wrong.

Comment: I have not tried to remove support for 1.0 and 1.1 on the server yet.  I was hoping to fix this without taking that step, but I will try that if it comes to that.  By the way, and I should note, that I am having some success when I put in my code this:
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
I've had to add this to the code everywhere I call the AWS API for it to work.

Comment: @kstubs Which versions of Windows and .NET Framework are installed on the web server?

Comment: Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile
KB2468871
KB2468871v2
KB2478063
KB2533523
KB2544514
KB2600211
KB2600217
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended
KB2468871
KB2468871v2
KB2478063
KB2533523
KB2544514
KB2600211
KB2600217

Comment: I ran another PowerShell script and came up with this.

v4.0
  Client  4.0.0.0

FROM: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

Comment: @kstubs Will the server let you install .NET Framework 4.8.1 ? [MS Download Page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework)

Comment: @kstubs Also, note that there were breaking changes going from .NET Framework 4.5 to 4.5.2 (ISTR), so if there is anything on the server which is using 4.5 or earlier then it would **not** be a good idea to update without sufficient testing.

Comment: 2 comments:  1) just tried to update to 4.8.1 and it is not supported on my operating sytem.  2) @AndrewMorton earlier but meant to reference Anderson-Matos  
However AndreMorton, I'm not sure what to make of the fact that there is an issue from 4.5 to 4.5.2 and not sure if this is messing me up or not.  I'm just not really sure what to do or expect from MS.  I feel like it is time to build a new server from scratch TBH.